# src tag for pdf in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, base64, thymeleaf

I'm working in Thymeleaf, I uploaded image using base64, but can't upload pdf documents using base64.
I'm wondering what will be the src value of pdf like images.

I already used image in Thymeleaf with base64 like this...

```html
<img th:src="${'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image.profileImg}" alt="">
```

But I don't understand how to accept pdf src in base64. I tried like this

```html
<iframe th:src="${'data:file/pdf;base64,' + myfile.profilePdf}" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<iframe src="data:file/pdf;base64,myfile.profilePdf" height="200%" width="300%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).